# How configure TypeScript + Express

Tags: typescript, express

I never get problem with the MERN stack, but it's the first time than i use typeScript.

I encountered an issue when starting my server.

when I run npm run dev, a new error occurs: Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 5000. I've tried different ports, but the error persists...

What could be causing this permission issue, and how can I resolve it?

It's worth noting that I tried opening Express with older projects, and it works fine. So, the issue doesn't seem to be related to my firewall.

What could be causing this permission issue, and how can I resolve it?

You can check my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/wilonweb/LMS-Mern-v1/tree/master/server)

Comment: Did you try port 8050? Btw, put .env on your .gitignore.

Comment: Yes i tried port 8050, 8080, 3000, 5000 ...
Thanks for the .env in the .gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .env file must use this format:

Correct:

```
PORT=8050
```

Incorrect:

```
PORT = 8050;
```

Do not include semicolons or spaces in your .env file.

Comment: Also, your .env should not be visible in github. Unless you have made it available to us for solving this problem, it should be listed in your .gitignore file so that your secret keys are not exposed